# Coreplot Intersection of X and Y axis

Tags: core-plot

Using the  Mac OS framework I have the x and y axis interesecting at zero ( X interesects Y axis at Y = 0 and vice versa ) however the Y axis is at the far left of the screen where it is not visible .

Is it possible to specify a fixed margin for Y axis from the left of the plot area irrespective of the X Range ( and still maintain both the axes interesecting at 0 respectively) ?

One way i thought of doing this ( forcing a margin for Y axis ) was via specifying a negative value for the low X however this does not scale well when doing wide ranges of X ( 100's vs 1000's) . I need an easier way to predictably make X intersect Y at a fixed pixel offset in the chart to render it consistently .

I've tried using the y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = 0 . it does what it is meant to do ( make y intersect X at 0 ) however the actual intersection point in the graph is not where I desire . I want to be able to control the location of that intersection  say 100 pixels for X and 80 pixels for y .

Answer (score 1):

Use the `axisConstraints` to hold the y-axis at the left side of the graph:

```
y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
```

If you always give the `xRange` of the plot space a location of zero, this will give the appearance you want.